# How do I search for a data, using Java HTTP?

Tags: java, http, search, get

I have a problem with Java HTTP. I am trying to make an app, which will send a certain request to the server and then get needed data. I have found how to send GET to the server, but I fully stuck then. I've found bunch of ways to parse search results in Google, but no info concerning other web resourses. So, for example, I'd like to make a custom search for transport tickets from some web-site - what should I do? If it somehow helpful - here is the code Im using for GET.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url = "https://www.example.com/tickets/search";
String charset = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();  
String param1 = "value1";
String param2 = "value2";


String query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s", 
     URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset), 
     URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));

URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response)) {
    String responseBody = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    System.out.println(responseBody);
}
    }
```

Comment: Do you need something like a web crawler ? Take a look on http://nutch.apache.org/

Comment: what's the specific problem?  Is it constructing the query URI, downloading the results or parsing the results?

Comment: I would say, that everything at once. I need to send the query, one problem, I have to, then, parse results into JSON, btw, - second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of need, I like using [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb) a Lightweight Java HTTP-Client for calling JSON REST-Services. Here is how you code would look like using this library (assuming that you expect a result in JSON):

```
    Webb webb = Webb.create();
    JSONObject result = webb
        .post("https://www.example.com/tickets/search")
        .param("param1", "value1")
        .param("param2", "value2")
        .asJsonObject()
        .getBody();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use it. It is possible as well to make a GET, right?

Comment: yes of course, it supports GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

Comment: Btw, is JSONObject belong to this library or for it I suppose to use another one?

Comment: it is a dependency of the library as you can see here https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb/blob/master/pom.xml#L27-L29